# Reading from FTDI D2XX device using Python3 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c#, python-3.x, linux, ftdi, d2xx

I am working with an FTDI device that has native software for Windows, but nothing available for Linux. I am trying to read data from the device using `pylibftdi`. I would like to translate `C# code` that is provided by the device manufacturer and purportedly works (unclear if this is true) but have not been successful. So far I have done the following:

1. Installed the Linux D2XX drivers based on these [instructions](http://cognionics.com/wiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DevicePairing). Installation was successful.
2. Followed the directions [here](https://iosoft.blog/2018/12/05/ftdi-python-part-2/) and [here](https://www.elektormagazine.de/news/ftdi-d2xx-and-linux-overcoming-the-big-problem-) to enable the FTDI device to connect to the Linux system.
3. After plugging the FTDI device into the Linux system USB port:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:0833 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd KU-0833 Keyboard
**Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC**
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The bolded device (`Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0403:6001`) is the device from which I would like to read.

4. Then installed `pylibftdi` and verified that the device was readable via the `pylibftdi` API:

```
$ python3
Python 3.9.5 (default, Jun  4 2021, 12:28:51) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys, pylibftdi as ftdi
>>> print(ftdi.Driver().list_devices())
[('FTDI', 'Cognionics Quick-20 20CH 1706Q20N', 'AI2SUN90')]
```

5. As is clear, the device is connected and recognized. However, when I try to read from the device, I receive empty arrays:

```
>>> d = ftdi.Device()
>>> vars(d)
{'_opened': True, 'driver': <pylibftdi.driver.Driver object at 0x7fd819320910>, 'fdll': <CDLL 'libftdi.so.1', handle 557bc3ca6560 at 0x7fd8190aee80>, 'device_id': None, 'mode': 'b', 'encoding': 'latin1', 'encoder': <encodings.latin_1.IncrementalEncoder object at 0x7fd819320a60>, 'decoder': <encodings.latin_1.IncrementalDecoder object at 0x7fd8190aefd0>, '_baudrate': 9600, 'interface_select': None, 'device_index': 0, 'list_index': None, 'ctx': <ctypes.c_char_Array_1024 object at 0x7fd819342c40>}
>>> d.read(100)
b''
>>> d.read(100)
b''
>>> d.read(100)
b''
```

6. This `C#` [code](http://cognionics.com/wiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CognionicsRawDataSpec) (provided by the manufacturer) purportedly works, but I haven't been able to test it. It seems like the easiest approach would be to translate this into `python` but even that is challenging as I do not know how to replicate the constants and `ftdi` function calls that are being used. The provided `C#` code is:

```
UInt32 ftDevCount = 0;
ftStatus = ftDev.GetNumberOfDevices(ref ftDevCount);

ftdiDeviceList = new FTDI.FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE[ftDevCount];
ftStatus = ftDev.GetDeviceList(ftdiDeviceList);
String[] deviceNames = new String[ftDevCount];

for (int c = 0; c < ftDevCount; c++)
{
deviceNames[c] = ftdiDeviceList[c].Description.ToString();
}

Connecting to a device and configuring the serial port settings

if (ftDev.OpenBySerialNumber(ftdiDeviceList[devID].SerialNumber) == FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
{    ftDev.SetFlowControl(FTDI.FT_FLOW_CONTROL.FT_FLOW_RTS_CTS, 0x11, 0x13);
    ftDev.SetDataCharacteristics(FTDI.FT_DATA_BITS.FT_BITS_8, FTDI.FT_STOP_BITS.FT_STOP_BITS_1, FTDI.FT_PARITY.FT_PARITY_NONE);
    ftDev.SetLatency(2);
    ftDev.SetBaudRate((uint)3000000);

    connectedName = ftdiDeviceList[devID].Description.ToString();

    return true;
}
else
{
    return false; //failed to open!

}

public byte ReadByte()
{
    UInt32 bytesRead = 0;
    byte[] t_data = new byte[1];
    ftDev.Read(t_data, 1, ref bytesRead);
    return t_data[0];
}

public void WriteByte(byte dat)
{
    UInt32 bytesWritten = 0;
    byte[] data = new byte[1];
    data[0] = dat;
    ftDev.Write(data, 1, ref bytesWritten);
}

//wait for sync byte 0xFF
while (byteInterface.ReadByte() != 255) {};

//read packet counter
int packetCount = byteInterface.ReadByte();

//read the 20 EEG channels
int NumEEG = 20;
for (int c = 0; c < NumEEG; c++)
{
    msb =  byteInterface.ReadByte();
    lsb2 = byteInterface.ReadByte();
    lsb1 = byteInterface.ReadByte();

    int tempEEG = (msb << 24) | (lsb2 << 17) | (lsb1 << 10);
}

int NumACC = 3;
//read the 3 ACC channels
for (int c = 0; c < NumACC; c++)
{
    msb =  byteInterface.ReadByte();
    lsb2 = byteInterface.ReadByte();
    lsb1 = byteInterface.ReadByte();

    int tempACC = (msb << 24) | (lsb2 << 17) | (lsb1 << 10);
}


//read packet tail
int impStatus = byteInterface.ReadByte();

//read battery voltage
int batteryByte = byteInterface.ReadByte();

//read trigger
int trigger = (byteInterface.ReadByte()<<8) + byteInterface.ReadByte();
```

7. Based on the documentation in `pylibftdi` github repo, I can find some wrapper [function calls](https://pylibftdi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pylibftdi/device.html) as well as a few [constants](https://pylibftdi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pylibftdi/driver.html), but I am unaware of how to turn just the setup snippet, for example, :

```
ftDev.SetFlowControl(FTDI.FT_FLOW_CONTROL.FT_FLOW_RTS_CTS, 0x11, 0x13);
ftDev.SetDataCharacteristics(FTDI.FT_DATA_BITS.FT_BITS_8, FTDI.FT_STOP_BITS.FT_STOP_BITS_1, FTDI.FT_PARITY.FT_PARITY_NONE);
ftDev.SetLatency(2);
ftDev.SetBaudRate((uint)3000000);
```

into something in `python`. I think I can reset the baudrate using `d.baudrate = 3000000`, and I can change the latency timer using `d.ftdi_fn.ftdi_set_latency_timer(2)` but I do not know how to set the data characteristics, what the constants mean (`FTDI.FT_DATA_BITS.FT_BITS_8`, etc.), and how to set the flow control identically to the `C#` code.

8. Other SO posts have also referred to the D2XX programmers guide found [here](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/ProgramGuides/D2XX_Programmer%27s_Guide(FT_000071).pdf) but didn't see a way to apply it to this problem

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you are using the device in UART mode - is that correct? If so: what is the reason not to use the VCP driver instead of the D2XX?

Comment: Manufacturer recommendation (http://cognionics.com/wiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CognionicsRawDataSpec): "It is recommended that you use the FTDI D2XX USB API rather than the virtual COM port interface. The D2XX is more reliable and allows a search by device name rather than arbitrary COM port numbers."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As response to the comment and as an follow up answer:

I cannot confirm the claim that D2XX is more reliable than the VCP from personal experience and the second one is only partially correct: one can e.g. use the VID:PID combination in most cases IIRC.

I would highly recommend to stick to the easier VCP + pyserial solution. But if you really want (or need to) use pylibftdi, you can take a look at https://github.com/codedstructure/pylibftdi/blob/4662ebe069eefd5a89709d4165e3be808cad636c/docs/advanced_usage.rst - it describes how to access none exposed functionality directly. The naming is slightly different e.g. ftdi_setflowctrl instead of SetFlowControl but you will figure it out. Just check https://www.intra2net.com/en/developer/libftdi/documentation/ftdi_8c.html .